# Compile DLL from python code

Tags: python, dll, compilation

Hi does anyone know if you can compile Python code into a Windows DLL file? How would you go about doing this?

Comment: I've found a way to compile to EXE using py2exe. But still looking for way to make DLL. I want to use the DLL in a C# project.

Comment: From your comment I guess you want to integrate Python with .NET. If so, there's [IronPython](http://ironpython.net/), which goes much further than just creating a DLL.

Answer (score 5):

One way would be to create a C or C++ library that embeds the Python interpreter and runs your Python code.

Another option would be to translate you Python code to C++ with [ShedSkin](http://code.google.com/p/shedskin/) and make that a DLL, although I wouldn't expect a very clean API to come out of this.

Comment: +1: Option 1  is the way it's supposed to be done.  Just embed Python in your app.